# FB App This method must be called with a Page Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, fbsdk

When i use this code:

```
<?php 

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$config = ...;

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\Page;

Api::init(
    $config['facebook']['app_id'], //APP_ID
    $config['facebook']['app_secret'], //APP SECRET
    $config['facebook']['app_access_token'] //Token generated by https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer for app
);

$page = new Page($config['facebook']['page_id']);
$leadgen_forms = $page->getLeadgenForms(); //heres an error
```

I get error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException: (#190) This method must be called with a Page Access Token in ...`

But when I put page_access_token in place of app_access_token (from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) i get error: `Uncaught FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument in ...`. When i remove line:

Comment: Show us where/how you _“put page_access_token in place of app_access_token”_

Comment: @CBroe, I just copy from Explorer and paste it in config in place of app_access_token;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you are working on lead-gen forms that are meant for pages only. Your profile must have admin/developer role assigned. You definitely seem to have missed/copied incorrect value for one of the below.
Below details are copied from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving for quicker understanding

> One can read leads or real-time updates by:
>
> **Using a Page Access Token**, i.e. the Page admin's access token for the page. Page access token also allows you to read ad specific fields
>   such as ad_id, campaign_id, etc., if you have atleast advertiser level
>   permissions on the ad account associated with the lead ad.
>
> **Using User Access Token** belonging to the page admin. To access all of the lead data and the ad level data, the access token should have
>   manage_pages and ads_management scope.
>
> You can manage user rights with Page roles. In addition, if you need
>   to allow leads download for user with non-admin role on the page, you
>   can whitelist it with leadgen_whitelisted_users endpoint.

Comment: How can I get these tokens?

Comment: Check it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Comment: I used different API objects for page and lead requests. I am still not sure why this is different now.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are not showing how to actually send a Page Access Token instead of an App Access Token or User Access Token.

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$config = ...;

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\Page;
use FacebookAds\Session;

$api = Api::init(
    $config['facebook']['app_id'], //APP_ID
    $config['facebook']['app_secret'], //APP SECRET
    $config['facebook']['app_access_token'] //Token generated by https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer for app
);
$page_api = $api->getCopyWithSession(new Session(
    $config['facebook']['app_id'], //APP_ID
    $config['facebook']['app_secret'], //APP SECRET
    $page_access_token  // <-- You can get this by accessing 'me/accounts' w/ the initial API
));
$page = new Page($config['facebook']['page_id'], null, $page_api); // <-- use the api with the Page Access Token here
$leadgen_forms = $page->getLeadgenForms(); //heres an error
```